# FullCalendare , modal

Tags: jquery, json, bootstrap, modal, fullcalendar

Estoy tratando de mostrar un calendario dentro de una ventana modal con FullCalendare , pero este no se muestra , sino se ejecuta un proceso como cerrar y abrir consola del navegador.

alguna ayuda por favor , de por que sucede esto , hice una prueba colocando el calendario en la pagina principal , lo muestra sin problemas.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Versión de full Calendar, ¿Estás usando bootstrap para el modal? ¿Qué versión?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.